Database import
I tried importing a file (database.sql) to my DB server and I get this error:

All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE insteadapp/config/database.sq|CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
'Newsnewsletter _groups _subscribers* ( 'group_id* int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 'subscriber_id" int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (group_id', 'subscriber_id'), UNIQUE KEY 'group_id' (group_id', subscriber_id*) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

The part of the file it refers to is this:
84 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `newsletter_groups_subscribers`;
85 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newsletter_groups_subscribers` (
86    `group_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
87    `subscriber_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
88    PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`, `subscriber_id`),
89    UNIQUE KEY `group_id` (`group_id`,`subscriber_id`)
90 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

I have tried swapping out 'NULL' with 'UNIQUE'
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `newsletter_groups_subscribers`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newsletter_groups_subscribers` (
    `group_id` int(10) unsigned UNIQUE,
    `subscriber_id` int(10) unsigned UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`, `subscriber_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `group_id` (`group_id`,`subscriber_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Then I get this different error:

Duplicate key name 'group_id'app/config/database.sqlCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nwsnewsletter_groups_subscribers ( group_id int(10) unsigned UNIQUE, subscriber_id int(10) unsigned UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY (group_id, subscriber_id), UNIQUE KEY group_id (group_id,subscriber_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

What am I doing wrong?

You are defining a schema that doesn't match your data.  In the first case, what you want to use as a primary key doesn't meet the criteria for a primary key.  In the second case, you declare a field as having UNIQUE values when there are duplicates in the data.

Hi Scott, thank you for your reply, can you give me an idiots guide to this as I'm fairly new to this having moved across from  HTML, even better could you suggest how those 7 lines should be written? The rest of the table imports correctly if I remove that small section but obviously that is needed. Any help would be appreciated.

Hi Colin, you are new to SO, when you think an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers

PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`, `subscriber_id`)

means you want to add the primary key of the table from group_id and subscriber_id columns, but primary keys can't be built on nullable columns,
so you have two choices:

remove the PRIMARY KEY definition and keep only the UNIQUE KEY

remove the nullability of that columns
group_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
subscriber_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,



Thank you so much for explaing that for me, i changed to 'NOT NULL' as in option 2 and it has worked a treat, I did try that before but left 'DEFAULT' in there aswell. Thank you

If you choose option two, unique key definition is a duplication of primary key, you can remove it
